# O que está errado no código em Python?? Bhaskara

Tags: python

```
import math

def Bhaskara():
a = int(input('Digite um valor para A '))
b = int(input('Digite um valor para B '))
c = int(input('Digute um valor para C '))

#(-b +- {-b² - 4 * a * c} ) / 2 * c

operacao = -b
raiz = (operacao * operacao) - 4 * a * c
raiz = math.sqrt(raiz)
divisao = 2 * c
# (operacao +- raiz) / divisao
x1 = (operacao + raiz) / divisao
x2 = (operacao - raiz) / divisao
print('X1 = {}'.format(x1))
print('X2 = {}'.format(x2))
if(__name__ in '__main__'):
Bhaskara()
```

Considerem o código indentado corretamente

Comment: dica: ao colar código aqui use o botão `{}` da barra de formatação depois de selecionar todo o código - assim ele mantem a identação correta.

Comment: Sobre o código - quando você usa `int`  no valor dos `input`, seu programa só vai funcionar pra valores inteiros  - use `float` para que ele possa funcionar com números decimais também.

Comment: Você tem que colocar dentro do def um tab ! se não ele não vai entender que está dentro do def

Comment: Muito obrigado a todos!!!
Se vocês não tivessem falado, eu não conseguiria achar
Aprendi Bhaskara hoje, na verdade, eu fucei a internet e achei legal a conta, mas vlw mesmo!!!

Comment: Não é necessário escrever uma resposta apenas pra dizer "obrigado". A melhor maneira de agradecer é **[aceitando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** a resposta que te ajudou. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/175966)

Answer (score 2):

Seu denominador está incorreto. O denominador na fórmula de Bháskara é `2*a`, e não `2*c`:

```
# Errado: divisao = 2 * c
divisao = 2 * a  # Certo
```

Além disso, você vai ter problemas quando as raízes forem imaginárias, porque o `math.sqrt` só aceita 0 e números positivos. Sugiro que implemente uma verificação antes de tentar aplicar `math.sqrt` com um número possivelmente negativo, ou trate a exceção.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado mas isso tá certo, a fórmula do delta é `b**2 - 4 * a * c` e `(-b)**2 == b**2`.

Comment: peço desculpas pela falta de atenção, e agradeço por me corrigir. Fui levado ao erro por (entre outras coisas como *preguiça de pensar* e *falta de atenção*) conta do comentário no código da pergunta

Answer (score 2):

Você está trocando o coeficiente quadrático `a` pelo coeficiente constante `c` no denominador da fórmula:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você também não está verificando se a raiz faz parte do conjunto dos números reais testando se o discriminante (*delta*) é menor do que `0`.

Segue sua solução corrigida e levemente modificada para um melhor entendimento e legibilidade:

```
import math

def Bhaskara( a, b, c ):

    delta = (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c)

    if ( delta < 0 ):
        return (None,None) # Raiz Negativa

    x = math.sqrt( delta )

    x1 = (-b + x) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (-b - x) / (2 * a)

    return (x1, x2)


if(__name__ in '__main__'):

    a = int(input('Digite um valor para A: '))
    b = int(input('Digite um valor para B: '))
    c = int(input('Digute um valor para C: '))

    x = Bhaskara( a, b, c )

    print('X1 = {}'.format(x[0]))
    print('X2 = {}'.format(x[1]))
```

**Teste #1**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Digite um valor para A: 2
Digite um valor para B: 7
Digute um valor para C: 3
X1 = -0.5
X2 = -3.0
```

**Teste #2**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Digite um valor para A: -3
Digite um valor para B: 2
Digute um valor para C: -1
X1 = None
X2 = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Não é necessário utilizar o módulo math pois é equivalente fazer `delta**(1/2)`, o código abaixo resolve a equação onde `x1` e `x2` são complexos contendo a parte real e imaginária (*caso exista*) das raízes.

```
def Bhaskara():
    a = int(input('Digite um valor para A '))
    b = int(input('Digite um valor para B '))
    c = int(input('Digute um valor para C '))
    delta = (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c)
    x1 = (-b + delta ** (1 / 2)) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (-b - delta ** (1 / 2)) / (2 * a)
    print('X1 = {}'.format(x1))
    print('X2 = {}'.format(x2))
    print(type(x1))    # Verificação do tipo da variável    

if __name__ in '__main__':
    Bhaskara()
```